# How to customize SharePoint Online columns/field for the modern experience document libraries?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online, jslink

In SharePoint 2013, and SharePoint Online classic experience, you were able to modify the way you view fields/columns in the list view, item view, new view and edit view by using JS link.

A client of ours needs to advanced search functionality to populate one of their columns using the SharePoint Online modern document library experience. I would be able to build the functionality using JSLink, but by the looks of it, JSLink is no longer supported.

Is there a replacement for JSLink in the modern design?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build field-extension in SPFx in modern list view, you could check below official guideline.

[official guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer)

Comment: Thanks! I'm definitely going to use it for the list view, and I think I'll be able to use List View Command sets for the adding, and editing specific list items. I'm not sure how I'm going to modify the edit, item view, and add pages... I'll see if I can figure something out